# What does these SAML terminologies mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, saml

**Background**

I'm trying to implement SAML authentication on my rails application. The rails application I implement will act as the service provider.

I use devise to manage user so I want to use [devise_saml_authenticable gem](https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable) to help me implement SAML.

But when reading its README instruction, I don't understand the SAML terminologies it uses. It ask me to check ruby_saml's GitHub page but I don't see explanation there too.

**Actual Question**

For the code:

```
config.saml_configure do |settings|
  # assertion_consumer_service_url is required starting with ruby-saml 1.4.3: https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml#updating-from-142-to-143
  settings.assertion_consumer_service_url     = "http://localhost:3000/users/saml/auth"
  settings.assertion_consumer_service_binding = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
  settings.name_identifier_format             = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"
  settings.issuer                             = "http://localhost:3000/saml/metadata"
  settings.authn_context                      = ""
  settings.idp_slo_target_url                 = "http://localhost/simplesaml/www/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php"
  settings.idp_sso_target_url                 = "http://localhost/simplesaml/www/saml2/idp/SSOService.php"
  settings.idp_cert_fingerprint               = "00:A1:2B:3C:44:55:6F:A7:88:CC:DD:EE:22:33:44:55:D6:77:8F:99"
  settings.idp_cert_fingerprint_algorithm     = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"
end
```

Please explain what some of the variables mean:

**issuer** - I should give my rails application a name and tell that name to my Identity Provider so that they know I'm a registered organisation allowed to use their login service, and this name is called issuer, right?

According to the code above, does my rails application have to write an action that handles request to its /saml/metadata? Or will devise_saml_authenticable gem already handle this for me?

**authn_context** - What's this for? Is this needed?

**name_identifier_format** - What's this for?

**assertion_consumer_service_binding** What's this for?

Note: I'm planning to use business ID as user's ID instead of just using email.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to resolve this is to ask the Identity provider for their metadata.

This describes all the attributes you are asking about.

You can then copy / paste from the metadata.